# adapterview inside adapterview & convertview

Tags: android, listview, adapter, convertview, android-adapterview

I have an adapterview (listview) and each contains some views including another adapterview(custom horizontal listview)

All the convert views look fine, I got convert from the listview's adapter when I scroll vertically and convert from the horizontal listview when I scroll horizontally.

My problem is when I call setNotifydatasetChanged on the listview,
it redraw all it's child rows from convertview, but child of each horizontal listview get an empty convert view.

So it rebuilds every item inside each horizontal listview.

I can avoid this by storing myself ~ 15 view for each listview row instead of relying on convertview, but it's quite ugly.

Do you know something better ?

Thanks.

Comment: do you reinstanciate your horizontal list adapter when drawing the convertview in the vertical list view?

Comment: Yes, but I changed, and it's the same

Comment: you probably need to keep your horizontal adapters in memory somehow to avoid recreating everything everytime

Comment: @wieux: I'm trying to implement similar adapterview in adapterview, but facing a lot of issues. Can you post your code or provide me some link to example-code for reference please?